# Ocaml Error : Unbound module when compiling

Tags: gtk, ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I'm learning Ocaml and currently I'm building a graphical interface for a game. I used `Graphics` and `camlimages` but now I would like to add some buttons. So I searched for Gtk2 and I'm having problems to compile now. This is a part of my code:

```ml
open Gamebase
open Game_imp
open Graphics
open Graphic_image 
open Images 
open Png 

let _ = GMain.init () 
 
let window = GWindow.window 
    ~title:"Simple lablgtk program"
    ~width:320 
    ~height:240 ()
```

I used

```
ocambuild -use-ocamlfind main.ml
```

before in order to compile combined with `_tags` file, but in order to include the gtk module, I tried

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg main.ml -o main
```

which seemed to work in a sample exemple, however when I combine it with my projet, I get `"Error: Unbound module Gamebase"`. I tried

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -I +gamebase -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg main.ml -o main
```

but doesn't seem to work.
Any hints and kind words are greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is the module gamebase is located ? in a specific ml file that is at the same location as main.ml ?

Comment: yes, gamebase.ml is at the same location

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg  gamebase.ml main.ml -o main
```

Just take care of the order with which you give the ml file : `gamebase.ml` must be given first, because `main.ml` has a dependency on it.

Comment: I got the error : Error: Could not find the .cmi file for interface gamebase.mli.

Comment: So I figured out that I should compile the mli first using : 
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg gamebase.mli main.ml -o main
but then I got Error: Unbound module Graphic_image
Since I'm not using Ocamlbuild I guess he doesn't check the _tags file ? 
Thanks

Comment: I believe so. regarding your first try : is "ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind labgtk2 main.native " working ? (without populating _tags file).

Comment: I got this error :
Solver failed:
  Ocamlbuild knows of no rules that apply to a target named labgtk2. This can happen if you ask Ocamlbuild to build a target with the wrong extension (e.g. .opt instead of .native) or if the source files live in directories that have not been specified as include directories.

Comment: typo in my previous comment : ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg lablgtk2 main.native

Comment: Didn't work at first, I had the Unbound module Graphic_image but this time there was a hint that I need a _tags file or myocamlbuild.ml. So I brought back the _tags file and now it's working :) 
Thank you !